# Calculate set of multilevel columns mean based on a lookup table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a two level columns as below. The first level can be group into `tech_one`, `tech_two`, `tech_three`, `tech_four`, `etc` and `mnt`. On the second level, the `ch` and `b` is separated by `_`, and `ch` can be extended with the value `ch0,ch2,...ch6`. Whereas, `b` can be extend as `bo,bi,bc` and so on, however,here we just limit for the case `bo`.

```
first   tech_one                      ... tech_four       etc       mtc
second    ch0_b0    ch1_b0    ch2_b0  ...       ch5                    
0       1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  ...  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038
1       0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  ... -0.742165  2.269755 -1.454366
2       0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  ...  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327
```

The objective is to get the average for specific group of `ch` for each of the `bo`

The grouping and their associate name are defined in the following `dict`

```
dict_ref=dict(ch_first=['ch0','ch3','ch6'],ch_two=['ch1','ch2','ch4'])
```

For example,`ch_first=['ch0','ch3','ch6']` means get the `mean` value for the 'ch0','ch3','ch6' for each `b` (e.g., `bo`,`b1`), and name it as group `ch_first`

Repeating this for all `ch` and `b` group, the expected is something like

[image]

The following code is drafted and generating the intended output. However, I wonder whether there is much more efficient and elegent way of achieving the objective.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

np.random.seed ( 0 )

arrays = [["tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_two", "tech_two", "tech_two",
           "tech_two", 'tech_three', 'tech_three', 'tech_four', 'etc', 'mtc'],
          ["ch0_b0", "ch1_b0", "ch2_b0", "ch3_b0", "ch0", "ch1", "ch2", "ch3", "ch1", 'ch3', 'ch5', '', '']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples ( list ( zip ( *arrays ) ), names=["first", "second"] )
df = pd.DataFrame ( np.random.randn ( 3, len ( arrays [0] ) ), columns=index )

remove_nan = [tuple ( '_' if x == '' else x for x in x ) for x in
              [(e [0], *re.split ( '_', e [1] )) for e in df.columns]]

n = len ( max ( remove_nan, key=len ) )
remove_nan = [t + ('',) * (n - len ( t )) for t in remove_nan]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples ( remove_nan )
df_cal = df.drop ( (['etc', 'mtc']), axis=1 )
top_level = df_cal.columns.get_level_values ( 0 ).unique ().tolist ()
dict_ref = dict ( ch_first=['ch0', 'ch3', 'ch6'], ch_two=['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch4'] )


all_df=[]
for tlevel in top_level:
    for nref in dict_ref:
        for llevel in df_cal.loc [:, (tlevel)].columns.get_level_values ( -1 ).unique ().tolist ():
            try:

                df_B= df_cal.loc [:, (tlevel, dict_ref [nref])] if '' == llevel \
                    else df_cal.loc [:, (tlevel, dict_ref [nref], llevel)]

                all_df.append(pd.DataFrame ( df_B.mean ( axis=1 ),
                                             columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples ( [(tlevel,nref,llevel)]) ))

            except KeyError:
                continue
df = pd.concat ( [df, *all_df], axis=1 )
print(df)
```

output:

```
   tech_one                      ...  tech_two tech_three          
        ch0       ch1       ch2  ...    ch_two   ch_first    ch_two
         b0        b0        b0  ...                               
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  ... -0.013595   0.410599 -0.103219
1  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  ... -0.270514   0.864436  0.653619
2  0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  ... -0.254812   0.156349 -0.347912
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason in particular you need to deal with the MultiIndex? They are usually more of a headache than being helpful. Is your data structured in a way, that you can tranpose the table and make the index levels simple columns instead? Like this:

```
df = df_cal.T.reset_index().rename(columns={"level_0": "tech", "level_1": "ch", "level_2": "b"})

          tech   ch    b         0         1         2
0     tech_one  ch0   b0 -0.155010 -0.769916  0.635031
1     tech_one  ch1   b0  0.614079  0.539249  2.383145
2     tech_one  ch2   b0  0.922207 -0.674333  0.944479
3     tech_one  ch3   b0  0.376426  0.031831 -0.912822
4     tech_two  ch0  NaN -1.099401 -0.635846  1.117016
5     tech_two  ch1  NaN  0.298238  0.676433 -1.315907
6     tech_two  ch2  NaN  1.326386  0.576591 -0.461585
7     tech_two  ch3  NaN -0.694568 -0.208299 -0.068242
8   tech_three  ch1  NaN -0.149635  0.396007  1.713343
9   tech_three  ch3  NaN -0.435154 -1.093062 -0.744755
10   tech_four  ch5  NaN  1.849264 -1.491258 -0.826439
```

(Note that your example DataFrame contains lots of NaNs for the b index, this is probably not intended).

With this pivoted DataFrame, you should be able to perform the kinds of operations you seek using simple groupbys, like:

```
ch_first = df[df.ch.isin(["ch0", "ch1", "ch3"])].groupby(["tech", "b"]).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks, I manage solve the `nan` and extend your suggestion from there.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to @w-m suggestion

Loop each of the `dict`

```
all_df=[]
for nref in dict_ref:
    df_ch = df[df.ch.isin(dict_ref [nref])].groupby(["tech", "b"]).mean().reset_index()
    df_ch['ch']=nref
    all_df.append(df_ch)
```

Append the `loop` output with the `transform` df as suggest by `w-m`. To get back the multicolumn presentation, used the `transpose`

```
df=pd.concat([df,*all_df]).pivot_table(index=['tech', 'ch','b']).transpose()
```

Finally, merge back other `df` that has been drop earlier.

```
df=pd.concat([df,df_bal],axis=1)
print(df)
```

The complete solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

np.random.seed ( 0 )

arrays = [["tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_one", "tech_two", "tech_two", "tech_two",
           "tech_two", 'tech_three', 'tech_three', 'tech_four', 'etc', 'mtc'],
          ["ch0_b0", "ch1_b0", "ch2_b0", "ch3_b0", "ch0", "ch1", "ch2", "ch3", "ch1", 'ch3', 'ch5', '', '']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples ( list ( zip ( *arrays ) ), names=["first", "second"] )
df = pd.DataFrame ( np.random.randn ( 3, len ( arrays [0] ) ), columns=index )

remove_nan = [tuple ( '_' if x == '' else x for x in x ) for x in
              [(e [0], *re.split ( '_', e [1] )) for e in df.columns]]

n = len ( max ( remove_nan, key=len ) )
remove_nan = [t + ('',) * (n - len ( t )) for t in remove_nan]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples ( remove_nan )

# Extract column no used for averaging
df_bal=df.loc[:,(['etc', 'mtc'])]
df_cal = df.drop ( (['etc', 'mtc']), axis=1 )
top_level = df_cal.columns.get_level_values ( 0 ).unique ().tolist ()
dict_ref = dict ( ch_first=['ch0', 'ch3', 'ch6'], ch_two=['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch4'] )

df = df_cal.T.reset_index().rename(columns={"level_0": "tech", "level_1": "ch", "level_2": "b"})
all_df=[]
for nref in dict_ref:
    df_ch = df[df.ch.isin(dict_ref [nref])].groupby(["tech", "b"]).mean().reset_index()
    df_ch['ch']=nref
    all_df.append(df_ch)

df=pd.concat([df,*all_df]).pivot_table(index=['tech', 'ch','b']).transpose()


df=pd.concat([df,df_bal],axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output

```
tech tech_four  tech_one            ...  tech_two       etc       mtc
ch         ch5       ch0       ch1  ...    ch_two         _         _
b                     b0        b0  ...                              
0     0.144044  1.764052  0.400157  ... -0.013595  1.454274  0.761038
1    -0.742165  0.121675  0.443863  ... -0.270514  2.269755 -1.454366
2     1.230291  0.045759 -0.187184  ... -0.254812  1.202380 -0.387327

[3 rows x 19 columns]
```